# Why can't my Nvidia graphics card drive more than two monitors?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I don’t understand why a graphics card—such as one made by Nvidia—isn’t able to run 3 monitors at any resolution but can run 2 monitors some much higher resolution.

I figured the main factor for determining the output of a card would be tied closely to the total number of pixels rendered, is that not true?

Comment: Is the question a general question? I read the question as if the model isn't relevant, it's more "what limits any graphic card supporting any number of monitors"? Obviously excluding limitations such as where to plug the VGA/DVI/HDMI cable in!

Comment: It's a general question, but the car I have is a 670m. I wish it could drive 3 displays and I was wondering why that wasn't possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main factor for the number of outputs is the number of outputs. Each display requires the GPU to provide a discrete data channel for it.

While there are devices like Matrox’ TripleHead2Go and the like, a graphics card doesn’t work that way. These devices are, in essence, a hack.

Imagine you have a display capable of displaying only 30 Hz and another display capable of displaying 120 Hz. Would you want your “worst” display to drag everything down? Or should every display but the “best” simply skip images? Or maybe color bits? Discrete outputs are the way to go when driving multiple displays.